# Change div height to child div's height on click with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div (divChatContainer) with a top div (divChatContainerTop) that have a "span" element inside it. I want the container div to be resized to the "divChatContainerTop" height when the "span" element is clicked (ie: minimize the chat window so only the "divChatContainerTop" appears).

HTML code:

```
<div id="divChatContainer" runat="server" style="overflow-y: scroll; box-sizing: border-box; word-wrap: break-word; width: 20%; max-height: 35%; position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0%; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #EBECEF; border: solid #3A5896; border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; border-radius: 1px;">
  <div id="divChatContainerTop" style="text-align: right; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; padding: 3px;">
                <span style="float: left; box-sizing:border-box;width:50%;overflow:hidden;">Left</span><span id="spanChatMinimize" style="float: right">X</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

External .js file:

```
document.getElementById('spanChatMinimize').addEventListener('click', function () {
     document.getElementById('divChatContainer').style.height = document.getElementById('divChatContainerTop').style.height + 'px';
});
```

In debug i notice it's not entering the function. Perhaps the syntax of adding the eventListener is wrong, or maybe the "span" element have other name (on MasterPage sometimes they have "ctl00_elementName"), but i guess it's not the case, as the container element is statically in HTML outside ContenPlaceHolder.

**EDIT**:
The following code WORKS to minimize

```
document.getElementById('spanChatMinimize').addEventListener('click', function () {
   document.getElementById('divChatContainer').style.height = 10px;
});
```

But the following code DON'T do nothing:

```
document.getElementById('spanChatMinimize').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('divChatContainer').style.height = document.getElementById('spanChatMinimize').style.height + 'px';
});
```

So i am assuming i am not being able to get "divChatContainerTop" or the "span" height. Can't we get a screen height instead of height property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I misunderstood the question last night. If you want to get the height of the div without setting the *height* property in the first place, you should try one of:

```
document.getElementById('divChatContainerTop').clientHeight
document.getElementById('divChatContainerTop').offsetHeight
document.getElementById('divChatContainerTop').scrollHeight
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bo6r4b9L/2/), logs three values and when you click on the span, height will change.

Reference:

- [Element.clientHeight - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)
- [HTMLElement.offsetHeight - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)
- [Element.scrollHeight - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

Comment: The divChatContainer have more things in it, its height does not come only from the "span" elements. The thing is, if i set "divChatContainer" "style.height" to "10px" for example, still not work. The click event isn't being associated to the "span" click. in debug, it doesn't go into function (middle) line. I checked and all elements are created and correct name (did a small function alerting all elements' ids).

Comment: @MrBilly addEventListener works. Console.log works if you click on the span.

Comment: @MrBilly see the jsfiddle example. Console.log works when you click on the span

Comment: The "divChatTopContainer" have the "span" height, that's why i want to set "divChatContainer" (which contains the spans) to the SPAN height, thus only showing the top container. The "span" must be shown, as it will be changes to "maximize" after being minimized, for the reverse process.

Answer (score -1):

Simple! you should have added your scripts at last(before closure body tag), becauase the dom need to find the elements you have referred in scripts,so it should  have parsed before. this will solve the problme of event not triggered but to get that chat like function you have to edit your code bit more
EX

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
etc etc
<div>
<script>
// your script or external file
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="divChatContainer" runat="server" style="overflow-y: scroll; box-sizing: border-box; word-wrap: break-word; width: 

20%; max-height: 35%; position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0%; box-sizing: border-box; background-color: #EBECEF; border: 

solid #3A5896; border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px; border-radius: 1px;">
  <div id="divChatContainerTop" style="text-align: right; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; padding: 3px;">
                <span style="float: left; box-sizing:border-box;width:50%;overflow:hidden;">Left</span><span 

id="spanChatMinimize" style="float: right">X</span>
            </div>
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById("spanChatMinimize").addEventListener('click', function () {
alert('hi');
     document.getElementById('divChatContainer').style.height = document.getElementById('divChatContainerTop').style.height 

+ 'px';
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

to get the height of div you should use

document.getElementById('spanChatMinimize').clientHeight;

or
document.getElementById('spanChatMinimize').offsetHeight;

this works!

Comment: The external .js file is referenced before </body>.

Comment: and after all your tags it ? like my sample?

Comment: Yes. Also the event listener isn't binding to the span element, as i need.

Comment: see my edit, run the code  and you will get the alert when you click span

Comment: @ Mr Billy, still any bug? let me know pls

Comment: Check my EDIT. Thanks.